# creating a csv files using perl

Tags: perl, csv

I have a multiple CSV files and want to create master file with unique entries only also want the location of entry. I am not able to figure out what to write for creating columns.

file 1

```
fragment
accb
bbc
ccd
```

file 2

```
fragment
ccd
llk
kks
```

output

```
fragment  file 1        file 2
accb        1              0
bbc         1              1
ccd         1              1   
llk         0              1
kks         0              1
```

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

use constant {
    FILE_1 => "file1.csv",
    FILE_2 => "file2.csv",
};

my %hash;
#
# Load the Hash with value from File #1
#
open my $file1_fh, "<", FILE_1;
while ( my $value = <$file1_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    $hash{$value} = 1;
}
close $file1_fh;
#
# Add File #2 to the Hash
#
open my $file2_fh, "<", FILE_2;
while ( my $value = <$file2_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    $hash{$value} = 1;    #If that value was in "File #1", it will be "replaced"
}
close $file2_fh;

for my $value ( sort keys %hash ) {
    say $value;
}
```

Comment: Your sample output doesn't look like CSV (it doesn't have any commas).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing files, removing duplicates and giving code in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969731/comparing-files-removing-duplicates-and-giving-code-in-perl)

Comment: Yes i know, actually its just a sample. My files consists of SMILES (eg. O=C(Nc1cc(Nc2ncccn2)ccc1)c1ccccc1,n1n(ccc1)CC, etc.). I was not able to upload it. So I gave simple letters.

Comment: Instead of setting your hash values to 1, try setting them to values that will allow you to work out which file the entry is in. E.g. for file 1, do `$hash{$value}++`, and file 2, do `$hash{$value} += 10`. You can then easily make the table in your third file.

Comment: @Bifffen If max read your comment,  it certainly didn't register: max recently asked another question like this with using the misunderstood phrase CSV. I think max wants the output to look left aligned in columns as shown above. That might be CSV if the separator is a tab. Or it could just mean aligned at specific columns. Since max doesn't say, one can't be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding information into the hash value is a good approach in cases like this. One way of doing this would be as follows:

```
my %hash;
#
# Load the Hash with value from File #1
#
open my $file1_fh, "<", FILE_1;
while ( my $value = <$file1_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    $hash{$value}++;
}
close $file1_fh;
#
# Add File #2 to the Hash
#
open my $file2_fh, "<", FILE_2;
while ( my $value = <$file2_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    $hash{$value} += 10;   # if the key already exists, the value will now be 11
                           # if it did not exist, the value will be 10
}
close $file2_fh;

for my $k ( sort keys %hash ) 
{   if ($hash{$k} == 1) { # only in file 1
        say "$k\t0\t1";
    }
    elsif ($hash{$k} == 10) { # only in file 2
        say "$k\t1\t0";
    }
    else { # in both file 1 and file 2
        say "$k\t1\t1";
    }
}
```

You can extend this approach for multiple files by using 100, 1000, 10000, etc.

Another possibility would be to make a more complex data structure which records the names of the files where the record exists, e.g.

```
for my $file (@array_of_files) {
    open my $f, "<", $file or die "Could not open $f: $!";
    while (my $l = <$f>) {
        chomp($l);
        $hash{$l}{$file}++; # store the file name
    }
}
```

This is useful if you've got a large number of files or want more descriptive/understandable hash data.

Comment: thank you so much, its working. how to get heading as file name in output.

Comment: For the first line of your output file, you can just do `print $out "fragment\tfile1\tfile2\n";` (replace `file1` and `file2` with the appropriate file names/variables). Then run the `for my $k (sort keys %hash)` loop to print out the data.

Comment: What should i do if i have multiple columns in every file and I want to compare particular columns only, but in output i want fragment, id_file1,file1(1 or 0), id_file2,file2(1 or 0) and so on columns.

Comment: post this question separately as it is easier to describe the question and answer properly on a new page.